# How do I make a setup.py file for pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze

I have a made a setup.py file for my pygame executive, but it gives a HUGE list of errors when i try to run the executable after it is built. I am using python 3.3 32 bit and the corresponding pygame. My source is

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Pygame Module",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "A simple pygame program.",
    executables = [Executable("pygame_module.py", base = "WIN32GUI")])
```

Help?

EDIT: this is the error i get:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXMPz.jpg
EDIT: this question is for cx-Freeze. I apologize for not mentioning that
EDIT: my source is

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
    while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

this works in the shell, but not when making a module. it says pygame is not a package.

Comment: Can you show at least some of the errors, maybe using a pastebin? Preferably the first ones, because they might cause later errors.

Answer (score 1):

I did it! in the folder `C:\Python33\include` i deleted the pygame folder that was being used instead of the real folder
EDIT! i reinstalled python 3.3.3 and it worked like i said and then stopped. re-installed 3.3.2 and it now works. i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know your problem, because I had the same problem myself, but I can't be sure without the Traceback. Try manually importing both the `pygame._view` and the `re` modules into each file of your program. Eg. put the lines `import pygame._view` and `import re` into each python file. If this doesn't solve the problem could you please post an error traceback, and I'll see what I can do.

Hope this helped.

EDIT: This was not the answer to the above question. I will edit again if the correct answer is found. See comments below.

Comment: No, still got the traceback error. i tried putting it in the setup as well, but it refused to compile that way.

Comment: Do you have 2 or more versions of python installed?

Comment: i have 3.3 32-bit with the corresponding pygame and cx-Freeze. if i have any other python versions installed i dont know about them.

Comment: In your pygame program did you import the `pygame` module first, or did you just use the `from pygame.locals import *`? If not try adding the line `import pygame` above the `locals` import.

Comment: i have no idea what happened, but the module will no longer produce the window pygame creates. that may be the problem

Comment: Did you add the import to the top of the pygame script?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `import pygame._view` line

Comment: Sorry I am at a loss, because the exact code works on my computer. Perhaps pygame is not installed correctly on yours.